# Cannot compile ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, osx-lion, rvm, clang

When I run

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

on Mac OSX Lion, ruby does not compile, and I get the following error in (.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log)

```
[2013-01-29 16:31:05] make
CC = clang
LD = ld
LDSHARED = clang -dynamic -bundle
CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -pipe 
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Users/will/.rvm/usr/include -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.2.1 -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  
SOLIBS = 
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
return t->num_entries;
~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
```

How can I get ruby 1.9.3 to install on Lion?

Comment: I have the same issue on Mountain Lion with 1.9.3-p374. I upgraded to Xcode 4.6 yesterday and am installing p374 via rvm .. curious if it's related to Xcode tools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you are using `clang`, according to this ticket http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5883 - it's not "fully" supported - you need to try using `gcc-4.2`, you get instructions for homebrew with running `rvm requirements`.

here is RVM ticket for this problem https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1480

UPDATE: Ruby-2.0.0 actually compiles better with `clang` then with `gcc-4.2`, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655034/497756

Comment: I am facing same issues while installing rvm on Mac, I am using following command to install rvm on Mac, "$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby". Is there any alternate way to install rvm using gcc?

Comment: Siddhart skip the `--ruby` flag and make sure to read `rvm requirements` before you install ruby: `rvm install 1.9.3`.

Comment: @mpapis: can you expand on the comment "Ruby-2.0.0 actually compiles better with clang then with gcc-4.2"?  I'm having trouble compiling Ruby 2.0 under gcc-4.2 -- see https://gist.github.com/rdpoor/5249186 -- is this what you're describing (and are there any resolutions)?

Comment: yes this is exactly that problem, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15655034/497756

Comment: On an OSX box this is the command you need to run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 --with-gcc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.

Comment: this works only on older OSX where there was `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

Answer (score 33):

With Xcode 4.6 I was also getting this problem.  I installed the command line tools which made gcc available in /usr/bin/gcc.

I managed to get it to work using:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc
```

NB. I dont have homebrew installed.

Comment: This compiled, but ended up using clang and crashed with errors when executed.

Comment: Although it returns the error `Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p374' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.`, it seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have rvm already installed, rvm requirements won't work. 
Install gcc 4.2 with homebrew and restart the rvm installation. Worked for me.

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using rbenv and ruby-build instead of rvm, you have to define, which compiler should be used to build ruby:

```
# this export must be done before every new ruby build
export CC=gcc
# use the version you wish to install
rbenv install 1.9.3-p385
```

If it doesn't work, you need to install Gnu C Compiler (gcc) first:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
# install gcc, only once needed
brew install gcc
# You can view the installed GCC version, currently gcc-8
brew info gcc
# Maybe you have to tell, which gcc version must be used,
# to get it working.
export CC=gcc-8
```

For older Systems or not up to date systems install old GCC 4.2 version:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
# install apple-gcc, only once needed
brew install apple-gcc42
# Maybe you have to tell, which gcc version must be used,
# to get it working on newer systems
export CC=gcc-4.2
```

Until the ruby folks build a clang compatible ruby version, you have to export the CC variable before every build of a new ruby version or simply add the export to your .bashrc oder .zshenv file.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me even with apple-gcc42 installed. Turned out that my `gcc` command was actually `clang`, and I had to use `export CC=gcc-4.2` to get the real thing.

Comment: Update: `brew install gcc` `export CC=gcc-8`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using Macports.

I had problems compiling and were getting the error "*Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p374' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.*"

Github was also down for maintenance so I couldnt try compiling using brew as suggested in the previous answer... This is what I did, and it compiled fine on Mountain Lion 10.8.2:

**First install Macports**

http://www.macports.org/install.php

**Then run:**

sudo port selfupdate

sudo port install apple-gcc42

sudo rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-gcc=gcc-apple-4.2