# OpenSSL error got when install Ruby 2.0.0 via RVM and Rbenv

Tags: openssl, rvm, rbenv, ruby-2.0

I am trying to install Ruby 2.0.0-rc1, but got error of OpenSSL.

System Env:
OS：MacOS 10.8.2 Mountain Lion
Compile ENV：Xcode CommandTools 4.6 xcode46cltools_10_86938131a.dmg

RVM Installment:

```
rvm get head
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

And I tried RVM pkg：

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

But got same error when I run `bundle`:

https://gist.github.com/4704589

Notice that it is not a certification error.
I searched Google a lot, but nobody got the same error.

---

And now my `rvm use system` broke too：

```
─(⚡refactory/test_for_git_server)─(￣▽￣)~*>rvm use system
Now using system ruby.
─(⚡refactory/test_for_git_server)─(￣▽￣)~*>which ruby
/Users/ranmocy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-rc1/bin/ruby
```

---

rbenv got error too:

https://gist.github.com/4704619

---

But when I compile ruby 2.0.0-rc1 from source by hand, there is no problem at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I had a similar problem today, and was taught a bit about **pkg-config**, the wonderful system that describes installation of libraries. As a way of paying back that explanation, **[I wrote about it](http://ollehost.dk/blog/2013/06/25/install-ruby-2-0-0-p195-using-ruby-build-and-pkg-config/)**.

TL;DR

Add this to your shell startup file (such as ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc). Then run the installation again.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

This makes the OpenSSL that isn't broken be found by configure scripts.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I managed to compile ruby2 with rvm and MacOSX 10.8

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install ruby-head --with-gcc=clang --verify-downloads 1  # see *
rvm use ruby-head
ruby -v
# => ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]﻿
```

More comments at: https://gist.github.com/iboard/5023717

Answer (score 0):

this looks like `clang` problem, see my other answer describing the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594287/497756