# Unable to install rvm on mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: rvm

Error running 'make', please read /Users/Megha/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: "Please read .../make.log". So what does it say?

Comment: It shows this error in the last :                               collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault: 11]      make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/digest/sha1.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/sha1/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot compile ruby 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592945/cannot-compile-ruby-1-9-3)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new experimental way of dealing with dependencies in RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/1544 :

```
rvm get branch /features/improved_dependencies
rvm pkg remove
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the command lines tools (install xcode via the app store - then open it to install the command lines tools). I am talking 1Gb+ so it will take some time.

After that, get brew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Update and run brew to install gcc:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Then RVM and ruby 1.9.3 should work:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
rvm install 1.9.3
```