# Error running 'make -j2' when installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

I'm following this tutorial on setting up Rails on your Mac :

```
http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/
```

When I get to **Step 6: Install RVM with Ruby 1.9.3**, and run `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` to install RVM, I get the following error :

```
Error running 'make -j2', please read ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

In make.log, here is what it generated :

```
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return t->num_entries;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I find this strage as I've followed this guide before on a similar setup and didn't encounter any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot compile ruby 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592945/cannot-compile-ruby-1-9-3)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error occurs when you compile Ruby with `clang` => https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7830

Unless you are interested in testing Ruby/`clang` compatibility you would be better with compiling ruby using `gcc-4.2` (see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5883 for details)

Skip the `--ruby` flag from the installer:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

RVM has a command to install all required packages using homebrew:

```
rvm requirements run force
```

In case homebrew is not available it will display the list of required packages.

**Alternative** there is a patch that could make it working with clang, install ruby using:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p385 --patch https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/download/3496/disable-werror.patch -C --disable-werror
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this when I try to install RVM. It's not yet installed and therefor, I can't run that command.

Comment: Upon reading your reply a second time, running the curl command you provided resolved my issue.