# Ruby 2.0 cannot extract source on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I am trying to install Ruby 2.0 on my Mac OS X 10.8 using the following steps 
http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion

All steps completed successfully until the very end. After I run

`rvm install 2.0.0`

It gives me the following output:

```
/Users/aaron/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0 has already been removed.
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 has already been removed.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time. No binary
rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0. Continuing with
compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary
rubies. Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date. Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'
already are up to date. Installing Ruby from source to:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while
depending on your cpu(s)... ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading
ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
tee: /Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/extract.log: Permission
denied tee: /Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/extract.log:
Permission denied ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to
/Users/aaron/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0 Error running
'__rvm_package_extract
/Users/aaron/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.bz2
/Users/aaron/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_856', please read
/Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/extract.log There has been an
error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter.  Halting the
installation.
```

Looks like it cannot extract the source. Any recommendations so that I can get this working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved this using `bash` instead of `zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have permission problems, try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: $rvm_path
```

Comment: I think you got it! I ran that command then re-ran the rvm install and this time it compiled and installed. However, when it got to "Installing rubygems-2.0.3 for ruby-2.0.0-p0" it gave me an error "Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0: .....Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully." Any idea why the rubygems won't install? Do I need to do it separately? Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: At the end it says, "please read /Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log" Here is a link to the file if it helps: http://bit.ly/YJG3KF

Comment: the problem is known, it's rubygems `--verbose` flag which triggers a ruby bug http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7992 it should not be harmful to rubygems and should work as expected - let me know if it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rvm get head` and run the installation again

Comment: I did both rvm get head and then rvm install 2.0.0 and it gives me the same result

Comment: Whats inside `/Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/extract.log` ?

Comment: Strange thing..it looks like there is no file. cat: /Users/aaron/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/extract.log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem. Make sure you have the latest Command Line Tools from https://developer.apple.com/downloads and run rvm install ruby --with-gcc=clang

I'm basically just repeating the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643486/cant-install-ruby-2-0-0-p0-with-rvm-error-running-make-j8)