# installing ruby 2.0.0 through RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am on Macbook Air (v. 10.8.4) and am trying to install ruby 2.0.0. I did `rvm get stable` then `rvm install ruby-2.0.0`. I get this error...

> Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
>
> ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your connection...
>
> ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247 (already extracted)
>
> ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #configuring - using Zsh, can not show progress, be patient...
>
> ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #compiling - using Zsh, can not show progress, be patient...
>
> Error running 'make -j4',
>
> please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/1373658495_make.log
>
> There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

I tried [Can't install Ruby 2.0.0-p0 with RVM. Error running 'make -j8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643486/cant-install-ruby-2-0-0-p0-with-rvm-error-running-make-j8) but I am still getting the same error. As in, I tried

I copied and pasted the log file into a google doc because it was 400+ lines. Link here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mwiL88KbWYfFge3XKQF2hOJjG_8PzYTdcRFxbZcpUeU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: there should be `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/137*_configure.log` can you show first 20-30 lines of it

Comment: which OS X version do you have?

Comment: There are multiple files that fit that requirement. Should I post all of them? And the version is 10.8.4.
EDIT: looks like they all say the same thing. Here you go, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bItAf9TCNrq2gSao2rz6pymgDVu5Xj0df8K6sjtWdUE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try running these commands in given sequence: ---

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
rvm get stable
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```